# Android: getting SSL certificate as stream or bytes[]

Tags: java, android, ssl, https

I need to check ssl certificate manually before trusting it in the X509TrustManager. How to download ssl certificate in android as **bytes or stream**? I know how to get ssl certificate as java object, but I need bytes[] or stream.

I registered socket factory

```
schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("https", new EasySSLSocketFactory(), 443));
```

registered context

```
SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
```

and owerrided

```
public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certificates, String authType)
            throws CertificateException
```

for ssl connection it works fine, but I have an certificate as java object, but not as input stream or bytes array.

Comment: Why? Nothing you can do with it as byes that Java hasn't already done for you. But if you must have the bytes, just call `Certificate.getEncoded()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`X509Certificate` has the member `getEncoded` which should return a `byte[]` of the encoded form of the cert.

Has this worked for you?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/cert/Certificate.html#getEncoded()

Comment: Oh yes! I forgot about this method, sorry, my bad :)